# How to share a variable among the threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I have two threads named `t1` and `t2`. They only make an addition to `total` integer variable. But the variable `total` isn't shared among these threads. I want to use same `total` variable in both the `t1` and `t2` threads. How can I do that?

My `Adder` runnable class:

```
public class Adder implements Runnable{

    int a;
    int total;

    public Adder(int a) {
        this.a=a;
        total = 0;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        total = total+a;

    }

}
```

My Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Adder adder1=new Adder(2);

        Adder adder2= new Adder(7);

        Thread t1= new Thread(adder1);
        Thread t2= new Thread(adder2);

        thread1.start();
        try {
            thread1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t2.start();
        try {
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println(adder1.getTotal());  //prints 7 (But it should print 9)
        System.out.println(adder2.getTotal()); //prints 2  (But it should print 9)


    }

}
```

Both print statements should give 9 but they give 7 and 2 respectively (because the total variable doesn't isn't by `t1` and `t2`).

Comment: Make it an instance variable of an object that you pass as argument to the tho threads. All accesses to it should be synchronized, or it should be an AtomicInteger, otherwise it's not thread-safe (except your two threads are executing sequentially, which makes them useless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way out would be to make `total` `static` so it's shared between all `Adder` instances.

Note that such a simplistic approach would be sufficient for the `main` method you shared here (which doesn't really run anything in parallel, since each thread is `join`ed right after being started). For a thread-safe solution, you'll need to protect the addition, e.g., by using an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html):

```java
public class Adder implements Runnable {

    int a;
    static AtomicInteger total = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public Adder(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // return value is ignored
        total.addAndGet(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: @javac no, unless you make it thread-safe. Concurrent access to mutable shared state is not thread-safe without synchronization.

Comment: @javac definitely not - it's sufficient for the simple `main` you provided. See my edited answer for a more complete solution.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks, but what happed if the 'total' varible is an wrapped Object?

Comment: @javac what do you by "an wrapped Object"? Do you mean a wrapper class like `java.lang.Integer`?

Comment: @Mureinik yes, Or a class that holds "int total".

Comment: @javac you could go down that route, but you'd have to somehow synchronize the blocks (or methods) that add `a` to `total`. Using a class like `AtomicInteger` does this for you - there's nothing magical here, just a relatively elegant implementation that uses the tools the JDK gives you.

Comment: @Mureinik okay, thanks a lot. Is it same for integer array?

Comment: @javac Understanding the fundamental concepts and rules of thread-safety is too complex for a StackOverflow comment. If you really need to deal with concurrency in Java, which is a complex, hard topic, then you need to read some serious material. At least the Oracle Java tutorial on concurrency, but I'd really suggest the book Java Concurrency in Practice.